# sublime text 2 - add visual mode without vintage mode

Tags: sublimetext2

My problem is that I would like to be able to use a visual selection without being in vintage mode.  Here are my key bindings:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} }
    , { "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} }
    , {"keys":["ctrl+h"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false}}
    , {"keys":["ctrl+l"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}}
    , {"keys":["ctrl+e"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}}
    ,{ "keys": ["ctrl+e"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
    ,{ "keys": ["ctrl+a"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} }
    , {"keys": ["ctrl+y"], "command": "copy"}
    , {"keys": ["alt+y"], "command": "paste"}
    , { "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "enter_visual_mode"}
]
```

As you can see I have vi-like commands except with ctrl modifier.  I want it this way. I would like ctrl+v to enter visual mode.  I saw in the Vintage mode default key bindings file, the command was defined like I have it defined.  Obviously "enter_visual_mode" is a command defined somewhere else in Vintage mode, but I don't know how to include that into my default editor.  If anyone could give some guidance on setting this up it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a plugin to support the behavior you want. I don't know of one that is fully flushed out, but I know this was a start to define different keyboard modes (like visual). Take a look at https://github.com/KonTrax/MultiBind. Untested but add the following to your key binding file should work.

```
// Toggle "visual" layout
{ "keys": ["ctrl+v"],
    "command": "multibind_toggle",
    "args"   : { "layout": "visual" }
},

// Show current layout in statusbar
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+\\"],
    "command": "multibind_show",
    "args"   : {  }
},

{ "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false, "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }]},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true, "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }] },
{"keys":["ctrl+h"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false, "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }]},
{"keys":["ctrl+l"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true, "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }]},
{"keys":["ctrl+e"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true, "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }]},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+e"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }]},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+a"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": true}, "context": [{   "key": "multibind.visual" }] }
```

You have `ctrl+e` defined twice, so I'm not sure which behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks, where would I put multibind.py?

Comment: Sorry, I got it working.  I made a new package (a new directory in the Package directory) with multibind.py in it, then added the keybinding:  {"keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true, "extend":true}, "context": [{"key":"multibind.visual"}]}.  This worked perfectly, it's too bad that this method involves a lot of code duplication though.

Comment: You could have just cloned the GitHub repo into your Packages directory. I'm not really sure what you are referring to when you say duplicate code. You are defining unique behavior based on some condition, so there really isn't anything duplicated.